# Why .onDelete triggers .onCreate if doc doesn't exist?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I try to delete a document that doesn't exist, .onCreate is triggered with an empty data?

EDIT (Minimially repro per Doug's request)

I have two Dart (Flutter) functions

```
Future<void> testCreate() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('test_collection').document('test_doc').setData(Map<String,dynamic>());
}
Future<void> testDelete() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('test_collection').document('test_doc').delete();
}
```

and two TS Cloud Functions (Firestore)

```
exports.onCreateTest = functions.firestore
  .document("/test_collection/{testDoc}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      functions.logger.info(`onCreateTest triggered. data = ${snapshot.data()}`);
  });
exports.onDeleteTest = functions.firestore
  .document("/test_collection/{testDoc}")
  .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
      functions.logger.info(`onDeleteTest triggered. data = ${snapshot.data();}`);
  });
```

If I execute testCreate(), testDelete(), testDelete(), the log shows

```
Beginning execution of "onCreateTest"
{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "message": "onCreateTest triggered. data = [object Object]"
}
Finished "onCreateTest" in ~1s
Beginning execution of "onDeleteTest"
{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "message": "onDeleteTest triggered. data = [object Object]"
}
Finished "onDeleteTest" in ~1s
Beginning execution of "onCreateTest"
Finished "onCreateTest" in ~1s
{
  "severity": "INFO",
  "message": "onCreateTest triggered. data = undefined"
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in detail what you're doing to delete the document that also triggers onCreate.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can duplicate behavior.  Document deletes should not trigger onCreate, but we need to see your entire system so we know what is actually going on.

Comment: The content of your log messages don't match the code you show for the functions.

Comment: Forgot the parens on snapshot.data(). Updating now...

Comment: @DougStevenson do you recommend I post this on Github as a potential bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but the first thing that jumps out to me is that [`.set()` and `.delete()` are both async functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#delete) that return Promises ([called Futures in Dart](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)). Your `testCreate` and `testDelete` functions should be amended to handle asynchronous tasks:

```
Future<void> testCreate() async {
    return await Firestore
      .instance
      .collection('test_collection')
      .document('test_doc')
      .setData(Map<String,dynamic>());

}
```

Edited to add: I've never used Flutter/Dart before, but this may put you on the right track!

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I actually had added async-await after posting but didn't bother updating my OP since it didn't change anything. I just updated